Fresnel's coefficients - Why is $H$ field considered over $B$ field?
Im currently studying fresnel's coefficients of reflection and transmission particularly the electromagnetic boundary conditions.
I understand that at the boundary the tangential coefficients of both the magnetic field and the electric field must be continuous.
However when trying to derive these boundary conditions, I don't understand why we consider the H field rather than the B field.
I speculated this may have something to do with charge density at the boundary but I still don't understand why we are considering the H field rather than the B field.


I think you can do the usual derivation of reflection/transmission laws both with H and with B, because linear medium is assumed, and $\mathbf B=\mu \mathbf H$. H has the "advantage" that the Poynting vector for radiation in dielectrics (the usual subject of this analysis) is defined as $\mathbf E\times\mathbf H$, which is simpler to write than $\mathbf E \times \mathbf B/\mu$.

The tangential components of the H-field are continuous. The tangential components of the B-field are not. Thus we can write an equation for the total tangential H-field components on either side of the interface.
You could of course write the H-field in simply in terms of the B-field and a relative permeability, as in the example you show, but this is only the case for linear magnetic media.
